# i have to pick the value of a paramter specified in text file and put it into the parameter value in xml

Tags: xml, shell

I have a text file

Values.txt(contents mentioned below)

```
IMSI,MSISDN
678,7890
```

I have an xml with IMSI and MSISDN values specified like this

```
  <item>
     <key>IMSI</key>
     <value>404720000000004</value>
  </item>
  <item>
     <key>MSISDN</key>
     <value>917329390086</value>
  </item>
```

I have to read the Values.txt and pick the IMSI and MSISDN values and put it into xml in the place of IMSI and MSISDN values.

Comment: do you have to do that via shell? it would be much more robust if you could use scripting language which has proper support for XML

Comment: yes....it would b nice if it is shell

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v FS=, '/[0-9]/{print "<key>IMSI</key>",$1,"<key>MSISDN</key>",$2}' input | \
    sed 's!\([^ ][^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)!<item>\n\t\1\n\t<value>\2</value>\n</item>\n!g'
```

Comment: how would i use my Values.txt is this....it has to pick values from Values.txt file

Comment: @user3073469, replace the `input` at the end of the awk command with `Values.txt`

Comment: Thanks...If i have multiple values for IMSI and MSISDN in Values.txt file? how it works...i am new to this...so need ur help..